# ARIMA variance of the residual values estimation in Python

Tags: time-series, python, variance, arima, residuals

I'm trying to estimate the variance of the error term in the best ARIMA(p,0,q) -- I'm making the hypotesis that my time series is stationary -- with 'statsmodels.tsa.arima.model' command in Python.

After running

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import arma_order_select_ic

res1 = arma_order_select_ic(data_frame,
                            max_ar = 5, max_ma = 5, 
                            ic = ['bic'],
                            fit_kw={'method':'css-mle'},
                            trend = 'c'
                            )
```

I get that ARIMA(4,0,0) is the best one, and then, I run the following code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA 

model = ARIMA(data_frame, 
              order = (res1.bic_min_order[0], 0, res1.bic_min_order[1])
              ) 
res = model.fit()
```

**My main goal here is try to estimate $\hat{\sigma}_{\varepsilon}^2$ from**:

$$y_t =  \alpha + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \phi_2 y_{t-2}+ \phi_3 y_{t-3}+ \phi_4 y_{t-4} + \varepsilon_t \qquad \varepsilon_t \sim iidN(0, \sigma_{\varepsilon}^2) \quad \forall t$$

And as far as understood, the coefficient 'sigma2' would give me this estimative (according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56817200/python-arima-output-interpreting-sigma2 ).

```
                                   SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:            cons_pcapta   No. Observations:                    6
Model:                 ARIMA(4, 0, 0)   Log Likelihood                  20.365
Date:                Mon, 01 Mar 2021   AIC                            -28.729
Time:                        13:06:42   BIC                            -29.979
Sample:                             0   HQIC                           -33.731
                                  - 6                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.0013      0.003     -0.422      0.673      -0.007       0.005
ar.L1          0.1244      0.305      0.408      0.683      -0.473       0.722
ar.L2         -0.7638      0.331     -2.304      0.021      -1.413      -0.114
ar.L3          0.1433      0.294      0.488      0.626      -0.432       0.719
ar.L4         -0.9818      0.028    -34.577      0.000      -1.037      -0.926
sigma2      1.551e-06   3.77e-06      0.411      0.681   -5.85e-06    8.95e-06
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.43   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 2.65
Prob(Q):                              0.51   Prob(JB):                         0.27
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.09   Skew:                            -1.58
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.17   Kurtosis:                         3.83
```

But trying to confirm it (mainly because I think it is a low value), I tried to estimate this variance by hand using

$$\hat{\sigma}_{\varepsilon}^2 = \frac{\sum_{t=0}^{N-1}( y_t-\hat{y_t} )^2}{N-5}$$

wich gives me

```
sum( (newdf - res.predict())**2 )/(len(newdf) - 5)
Out[26]: 0.0014486559274494817
```

A quite different value. I know that in statsmodel the parameter estimation is made by state space representation (using Kalman Filter, I guess -- https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/statespace.html ), but the results for $\hat{\sigma}_{\varepsilon}^2$ shouldn't be closer at least?

Thanks in advace

Comment: I just realized that the problem is basically a rounding issue hehe